# Why won't pandas.read_excel run?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, xls

I am trying to use pandas.read_excel but I keep getting " 'module' object has no attribute 'read_excel' " as an error in my terminal as shown

```
  File "read.py", line 9, in <module>
  cols = pd.read_excel('laucnty12', 'Poverty Data', index_col='State', \\    na_values=['NA'])
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_excel'
```

I have tried pd.read_excel() and pd.io.parsers.read_excel() but get the same error. I have python 2.7 installed and other parts of pandas work fine such as xls.parse and read_csv. My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *

xls = pd.ExcelFile('laucnty12.xls')
data = xls.parse('laucnty12', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
cols = pd.read_excel('laucnty12', 'Poverty Data', index_col='State', na_values=['NA'])

print cols
```

Comment: What are you trying to do that xls.parse can't do? (Agree, that you should update pandas to the latest stable version)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your script is called "read.py". The Python file that defines read_excel already imports another module called "read" - so when you try and run your "read.py" script, it squashes the old "read" module that pandas is using, and thus breaks read_excel. This problem can happen with other "common" short names for scripts, like "email.py".

Try renaming your script.

Comment: For me: my (test) package name was `pandas`. I have renamed it and now it is working

Comment: Mine was called inspect.py and renaming it fixed the problem. I wasn't aware of these naming constraints!

Answer (score 4):

```
df = pd.read_excel(filepath + 'Result.xlsx')
```

Check whether the extension of excel file is `xls` or `xlsx` then add the same in the query. I tried and its is working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean `pd.io.excel.read_excel()`

Comment: Yes I do thank you. Unfortunately the issue is the same

Comment: Sorry, Actually the error changes to " no attribute 'excel' ", instead or " no attribute 'read_excel' "

Comment: Strange, that works to me. What version of pandas are you using? Try `print pd.version.version`

Comment: I have 0.10.1. I downloaded it recently

Comment: I've went around this issue now I am using a csv file. Thanks anyway for the help

Comment: Ok, but take into account that 0.10.1 is not recent at all, last pandas version is 0.13.1, probably your version doesn't include `read_excel` yet

Comment: It's definitely worth upgrading; not only have there been substantial enhancements since 0.10.1, there have been many important bug fixes.