# Import error: cannot import numpy and pandas on Anaconda prompt

Tags: python, pandas, module, attributes

I have installed numpy 1.16.4 and pandas 0.24.2. However i still get below error message;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\FLUXNATURE\Desktop\khady_01\pandas.py", line 8, in'module'
import pandas as pd     
File "C:\Users\FLUXNATURE\Desktop\khady_01\pandas.py", line 9, in 'module'
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\FLUXNATURE\Desktop\use.xlsx')
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_excel'
```

when running the code below:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\FLUXNATURE\Desktop\use.xlsx')
print(df)
```

I'm running this file in Anaconda prompt with windows. Kindly help on this.

Comment: try change the name of your file `pandas.py` to other that not contains pandas or read example test.py. So use Save as...test.py and run again

Comment: Please go through this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947813/why-wont-pandas-read-excel-run